# shared libraries libgconf-2.so.4 is missing

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver, rhel6

I want to install [chromedriver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.21/) in one of the AWS EC2 instance which is linux(`Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 Santiago - 64 bit`). While installing the chromedriver, we ran into issue due to missing packages. I could find the package [here](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libgconf-2.so.4&submit=Search%20...&system=&arch=) but this in turn requires many other packages. Using any other AMI is not an option.

Error is -

```
error while loading shared libraries libgconf-2.so.4 cannot open shared object file
```

Comment: I am trying to do the same in AWS Linux AMI. Whenever I try to do yum provides */libgconf-2.so.4 I get below error : yum provides */libgconf-2.so.4
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No matches found

Answer (score 66):

I am using Ubuntu x64 and yum didn't work for me. But I found somebody mentioning simply use
`$sudo apt install libgconf-2-4`
worked for me to install the libgconf.

Comment: `Package 'libgconf2-4' has no installation candidate` on Ubuntu 19.10 but `sudo apt install gconf2` worked.

Comment: actually it is `libgconf-2-4`, not `libgconf2-4`

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04 also `sudo apt install gconf2` worked for me

Answer (score 25):

---

Please ask yum for the file, libgconf-2.so.4 : $ `yum provides */libgconf-2.so.4`

Install GConf2 : `# yum install GConf2`

Packages http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.8/os/ ... and updates http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.8/updates/

The chromedriver depends on the same packages / files as GConf2, and then some. Please see for yourself : $ `ldd chromedriver` , where 'chromedriver' is the unzipped executable.

---

EDIT :

Solution for the chromedriver issue : Install a chromedriver for RHEL 6, `chromedriver-31.0.1650.63-1.el6.x86_64.rpm` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNX1c0UWlGOWpZOHM/view?usp=sharing

Please download the package, and 1) `cd Downloads/` 2) `yum install chromedriver-31.0.1650.63-1.el6.x86_64.rpm` ... and you have `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`

---

P.S. : The EL6 chromedriver was built from the source package chromium-31.0.1650.63-1.el6.**src**.rpm

---

Comment: Tried but now ran into another dependency issue - /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./chromedriver) .

Comment: GLIBCXX_3.4.15 is an object in libstdc++.so.6.0.15 (  gcc version 4.5 ). Either compile gcc version 4.5 or 4.6 or 4.7 to get a new ibstdc++.so.6***. Or plug out llibstdc++.so.6.0.17 from libstdc++6-4.7.4_20140612-2.1.x86_64.rpm http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/SLE-11/x86_64/libstdc++6-4.7.4_20140612-2.1.x86_64.rpm . libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.17 works very well. Tested with Firefox and chromedriver : CentOS6.8 - 64. -

Comment: looked at the gcc version on the box - rpm -qa | grep -i gcc
libgcc-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64 .. I already have gcc 4.7.7. But still when I try starting chromedriver..runs into the same error... What do you mean by plug out llibstdc++.so.6.0.17..I'm not clear with this..

Comment: Changing the system llibstdc++ appears not to be a good idea. (  The g++ compiler won't work.) Please see the "chromedriver solution" in the edited post. -

Comment: you saved my life! I've been looking for a cause for an hour... even this post is old the simple `ldd` command helped me to find what was missing and grab it from package installer `cache`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read [this CentOS thread](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5807#p27860) about your `GLIBCXX_3.4.15`.  Especially apropos is [this answer](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5807#p27858) on the thread, especially the [FAQ](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-472ce8446ebcfc82ca1800f775ba0e629ac835c7) it references.

CentOS (which aims to be as compatible with RHEL as possible) is a curated LTS distribution (as is RHEL).  You might find a version of chromedriver compiled for RHEL 6 in one of the many repositories.  If not, you'll probably have to build it yourself.